# Strange syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, ide, visual-studio-2015

I don't know which color setting to change to fix the following problem in Visual Studio 2015. It seems that a lot of color settings have shifted around, so fixes from previous versions (such as importing my theme from Visual Studio 2013) are not entirely applicable.

Anyone know which setting affects the background color of individual symbols?

In C#, you can see that the selected line symbols have a darker background than the color set for the currently selected line.

[image: C# syntax highlighting]

In Razor, you can notice that the individual symbols have a darker background than the color set for the Razor background.

[image: Razor syntax highlighting]

Answer (score 0):

Goto "Tools" > "Options" > "Environment" > "Fonts and Colors".
Click `Use Defaults`.

Alternatively you could also look exactly for the in individual symbols and set them to your prefered color.

Comment: How will changing keybinds affect colors?

Comment: I don't want to reset everything just for a minor color tweak. It took a long time migrating from VS2013 to VS2015 because colors changed. I really just need to know the name of the entity which controls colors of symbols.